# WCF: Handler "svc-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" has a bad module "IsapiModule"

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, .net-4.0, isapi

When browsing to my .svc endpoint in a browser I get this message: **Handler "svc-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" has a bad module "IsapiModule"** (On 64-bit Windows the message is: **Handler "svc-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" has a bad module "IsapiModule"**).

I can't find IsapiModule anywhere in IIS. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Make sure the appropriate IIS features are installed. Go to Control Panel > Programs & Features > Turn Windows features on or off, then select everything under *Internet Information Services > Web Management Tools* and *World Wide Web Services*, and *Microsoft .NET Framework*.

2) From a Visual Studio command prompt, run the following commands:

```
aspnet_regiis -i -enable

ServiceModelReg.exe -r
```

3) Restart IIS.